# Hadoop's HDFS with Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to cluster-computing and I am trying to set up a minimal 2-node cluster in Spark. 
What I am still a bit confused about: Do I have to set up a full Hadoop installation first oder does Spark ship with an included Hadoop version inside?

The stuff I find about Spark does not really make it this clear. I understood that Spark is meant as an extension to Hadoop rather than replacing it, but if it requires an independently running Hadoop system does not get clear to me.

I require a HDFS, is it thus enough to just use the file-system part of Hadoop?

Could someone point this probably obvious thing out to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache Spark is independent from Hadoop. Spark allows you to use different sources of data (incl. HDFS) and is capable of running either in a standalone cluster, or using an existing resource management framework (eg. YARN, Mesos).

So if you're only interested in Spark, there is no need to install Hadoop.

Comment: However, if you plan to use Hadoop, Spark must be compiled against Hadoop binaries. See for more information: https://etushar89.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/building-apache-spark-against-specific-hadoop-version/

Comment: Thanks so far.
If I want to use HDFS I will have to install the entire Hadoop package although I probably would not have to go through the entire Hadoop configuration steps if I just care for HDFS, right?

Comment: You should care about the resource manager too, in case you are going to use it (YARN). If you are going to run Spark on standalone mode, I understand you are not going to need it.

Comment: If you want to avoid setting up your own cluster, you could use Amazon S3 instead of HDFS and avoid all the configuration work.

Comment: If you want to use HDFS, you need to fully configure the Hadoop. Hadoop is the 'OS' that enables HDFS, and without Hadoop you won't have HDFS accessibility.