# How do I set up a HDFS file system to run a Spark job with HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am interested in running Spark in standalone mode with Minio/HDFS.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368616/hadoops-hdfs-with-spark) asked exactly what I want: "I require a HDFS, is it thus enough to just use the file-system part of Hadoop?" -- but the accepted answer was not helpful, as it did not mention how to use HDFS with Spark.

I have downloaded Spark 2.4.3 pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7 and later.

I have followed the Apache Spark tutorials and successfully deployed one master (my local machine) and one worker (my RPi4 on the same local network). I was able to run a simple word count (counting words in `/opt/spark/README.md`).

Now I want to count words of a file that exists only on the master. I understand that I will need to use HDFS for this to share files across the local network. However, I don't have any idea how to do this, despite perusing both the Apache Spark and Hadoop documentation.

I am confused about the interplay between Spark and Hadoop. I don't know if I should be setting up a Hadoop cluster in addition to a Spark cluster. [This tutorial on hadoop.apache.org](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) doesn't seem to help, as it says that "you will need to start both the HDFS and YARN cluster". I want to run Spark in standalone mode, not YARN.

What do I need to do in order for me to run

```scala
val textFile = spark.read.textFile("file_that_exists_only_on_my_master")
```

and have the file be propagated to the worker nodes, i.e. not get a "File does not exist" error on the worker nodes?

Comment: Get a VM from mapR - they still extra and it's all there.

Comment: @thebluephantom not sure what you mean "they still extra". Will take a look at mapR's VM, but would like to deploy on my own if possible.

Comment: Indeed #$@%$^  exist

Comment: Get a VM from Cloudera, Hortonworks or MapR. They all include hdfs setup on those VM. On Windows, unfortunately it is very difficult to set this up and even difficult to start up all services.

Comment: @PiyushP I am on Linux running Ubuntu 18.04 on the master node and HypriotOS on the Raspi.

Comment: @LieuZhengHong did you set up Hadoop on your machines? You need to install hadoop on all machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up MinIO instead, and wrote the following Github Gist on instructions.

The trick is to set up `core_site.xml` to point to the MinIO server.

Github Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/lieuzhenghong/c062aa2c5544d6b1a0fa5139e10441ad)

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/lieuzhenghong/c062aa2c5544d6b1a0fa5139e10441ad.js"></script>
```